# Django setting default values for user create Form does not work on all fields

Tags: python, django-forms

I have bee trying to set the initial values for a user creation form
but I can only set the values for username and email not password1 and password2.

the view:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = CreateGamerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/login')
    initial_data = {
        'username' : 'Username',
        'email' : 'Email address', 
        'password1' : 'Pasasasdsword',
        'password2' : 'Password confirmation',
    }
    form = CreateGamerForm(initial=initial_data)
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/sites/register.html', context)
```

the form:

```
class CreateGamerForm(UserCreationForm):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

the html code for the form

```
<form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="LoginRegister-icon-wrap"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></div></i></td>
                <td>{{form.username.label}}</td>
                <td>{{form.username}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="LoginRegister-icon-wrap"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></div></td>
                <td>{{form.email.label}}</td>
                <td>{{form.email}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="LoginRegister-icon-wrap"><i class="fa-solid fa-key"></i></div></td>
                <td>{{form.password1.label}}</td>
                <td>{{form.password1}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="LoginRegister-icon-wrap"><i class="fa-solid fa-key"></i></div></td>
                <td>{{form.password2.label}}</td>
                <td>{{form.password2}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        <div id="submitButton-wrap">
            <input type="submit" name="Create User">
        </div>
    </form>
```

the resulting website:
[register website Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2PYC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround, but I would love to know why Im not able do set the initial value for the password fields

the workaround:
i added this script to the html

```
<script>
   var form_fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
   form_fields[1].placeholder='Username..';
   form_fields[2].placeholder='Email..';
   form_fields[3].placeholder='Enter password...';
   form_fields[4].placeholder='Re-enter Password...';
</script>
```

Comment: Please, do not use the answers if you want to ask questions. Just edit your question.